# JQuery datepicker init the selector/field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

is it possible to fill the input field with a date which uses the same format as i would select it with the datepicker? For example i have a value (e.g. new Date()) in my input field before i select a date with the datepicker and i want it to have the same format as i would select it.

thx

kukudas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [demo site](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html), new Date().asString() is used to select today and it is formated, as one would expect.

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
```

EDIT:

You have to make sure, you set the Date.format correctly. Here is a working example for the german date format:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>jQuery datePicker simple datePicker demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/date.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/styles/datePicker.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        Date.format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

        $(function(){
            $('.date-pick').datePicker()
                .val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="date1">Date 1:</label>
    <input name="date1" id="date1" class="date-pick" />
</body>
</html>
```

Note, the script http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/date.js extends the Date.prototype and sets "Date.format" to 'dd/mm/yyyy'. I'm overriding this with 'dd.mm.yyyy'.

Comment: i tried that but my input field is empty however .val(new Date()) works but not in the format my datepicker uses.

Comment: I have attached datepicker to some HTML textboxes using CSS class name & `onSelect` event handler I need to know the selector class name on which current `onSelect` happened.. the elements have 2 other classes applied other then the one I am using to attach datepicker

Comment: @techie_28 I don't get what you're saying/asking. You tried my example and it didn't work for you? Could you provide a jsfiddle or codepen or similar?

Comment: @TimBüthe say 3 boxes has datepicker `jQuery('.box1,.box2,.box3').datepicker({onSelect:function(){...}});`.Each box has other classes as well `class="text box1 float"` now while writing logic in `onSelect` I need to determine if the current box is box1,box2 or box3?

Comment: @TimBüthe I examined the instance object dump there are values which shows all the classes but none is there like `selector:box2` etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understand what the problem is?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date_field').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        constrainInput: false});
});
```

and just have a standard value in the input field you have:

```
<input name="date_field" id="date_field" value="2008-04-16" />
```

or you could just set the value in document.ready

```
$('#date_field').val("2008-04-16");
```

after you add the datepicker.
I'm not sure if that's what you mean?

Ok, after your comment I have a feeling you want something similar to this:

```
var my_date = new Date(); //This is the Date object that you're getting from external source
$('#date_field').val(my_date.getFullYear()+"/"+my_date.getMonth()+"/"+my_date.getDate());
```

This should set the value in the field to be 2008/04/26 (or whatever)

Comment: the value comes from an external system which is probably formated like this Tue May 12 2009 16:32:05 GMT+0200 but after selecting the format is for example 05/12/09. Basicly i want the value which is populated in my input field have the same formating as i would select it from the datepicker. I'm kinda new to this stuff so i don't know how i could better explain i hope this is more clear.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to change this my_date.getFullYear()+"/"+my_date.getMonth()+"/"+my_date.getDate() into calling the same format/parse method which the datapicker would use ?

Comment: i think i need to use this:
var dateFormat = $('.selector').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat');
which i read in the documentation to get the format style of my datepicker. and after that i should be able to format and set the value, but somehow i get the code to get the dateFormat dont work.

Comment: it seems that using var dateFormat = $('.selector').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat'); i get an object which most likly contains the informating i need. I probably could could format the date like this $.datepicker.formatDate(dateformat, new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26)); however this is not working, i think i need the actual value of the option any suggestions ?